# MySQL Select find similar item that has stock

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have this resultset of my table of products, while trying to return correct results in the last two columns, similar_sku_exists   and similar_sku_in_stock.

The goal is, to first determine whether a similar sku exists in the table and return yes/no.

second to determine if either one of the similar skus have stock and return that sku name/s.

A similar sku is defined by the same sku name + first letter of grade. 
Eg, all instances of "ABC-11-A" will be similar as they bear the same condition of new. Likewise "ABC-11-B" will be similar in that they are all refurb condition.

```
id  sku            condition     grade   stock  similar_sku_exists  similar_sku_in_stock
1   ABC-11-A1      new           A1      0      yes                 ABC-11-A2
2   ABC-11-A2      new           A2      10     yes 
3   ABC-11-B1      refurb        B1      10     yes 
4   ABC-11-B2      refurb        B2      0      yes                 ABC-11-B1|ABC-11-B2-LP
5   ABC-11-B2-LP   refurb        B2-LP   10     yes 
6   DEF-2-F-A1     new           A1      0      no  
7   DEF-2-G-B1     refurb        B1      10     yes 
8   DEF-2-G-B2     refurb        B2      0      yes                 DEF-2-G-B1
```

So far i have this query but that dosn'nt seem to return correct results

```
select 
    id,
    sku,
    `condition`,
    grade,
    stock,
    case when left(p.sku, length(p.sku)-length(p.grade)+1) 
            in (select left(p.sku, length(p.sku)-length(p.grade)+1))
         then 'yes' else 'no' end as similar_sku_exists,
    if(p.stock = 0, 
         case when left(p.sku, length(p.sku)-length(p.grade)+1) 
            in (select left(p.sku, length(p.sku)-length(p.grade)+1) and p.stock >0
         ) 
         then group_concat(distinct(p.sku) separator '|') 
         else '' end,'') as similar_sku_in_stock

    from products as p
```

Much appreciated any tought

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to get the similar skus in stock:

```
select p.*,
       (select group_concat(p2.sku)
        from products p2
        where substring_index(p2.sku, '-', 1) = substring_index(p.sku, '-', 1) and
              left(subsctring_index(p2.sku, '-', -1), 1) = left(substring_index(p.sku, '-', -1), 1) and
              p2.sku <> p.sku and
              stock > 0
       ) similar_skus_in_stock
from products p;
```

A similar query can be used to determine if similar skus exist.

Comment: On the right path but substring_index(,,1) would not work as my skus may have multiple hyphens, some with 7 or 8, sorry i should've been clearer on that part. Thats why i originally combined left(p.sku, -length(p.grade)) to have the full sku less grade as identifier. Edited op

Comment: Thank you works great! The above issue is only with skus of grade B2-LP which are not populated. Rest works just fine

Comment: I have to revisit here, my table has more than 50k records and your version of subquery takes 2+ minutes, how do i transform the code into a join query to optimize performance?

Comment: @joell . . . That would be another question.  But the place to start is to structure the data so the `join` keys do not require any funky functions to do their match.